# 301 redirect because of slash

Tags: apache, redirect

so I am optimizing my website to run as fast as possible, and pingdom tools are showing me that my url is redirected by 301 to slash-version. Of course for no reason. I dont have it in htaccess either.

Pingdom says:

Minimize redirects

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

http://domain.com/projects/project
http://domain.com/projects/project/

I have seen article about this on yahoo, and I have seen people doing it on purpose, but I haven't seen solution how to eliminate this issue. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: http://domain.com/projects/project/ redirects to the index page at that directory

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

But keep in mind there's a [possible security issue by turning this off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is active (Options +Indexes) and DirectoryIndex is set to a valid resource (say, index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html file. But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.